# How to use multiple Counters.counter in a contract?

Tags: solidity, remix

```
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract MyContract is ERC721, Ownable {
    using Strings for uint256;
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;

    Counters.Counter private totalSupply;
    Counters.Counter private commonSupply;
    Counters.Counter private rareSupply;
    ....
```

Answer (score 1):

However you like :)

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.3;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";

contract EnumerableMap {
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;

    Counters.Counter public totalSupply;
    Counters.Counter public commonSupply;
    Counters.Counter public rareSupply;
    
    enum Counts {
        totalSupply,
        commonSupply,
        rareSupply
    }

    function increment(Counts _count) external {
        if(_count == Counts.totalSupply) {
            totalSupply.increment();
        } else if (_count == Counts.commonSupply) {
            commonSupply.increment();
        } else {
            rareSupply.increment();
        }
    }
}
```